# How to find value of $\cos 2\alpha$ and $\cos 2\beta$

Tags: trigonometry

Consider the following simultaneous equations:
$$
3 \cos^2 \alpha + 2 \cos^2 \beta =4\\ 
3 \sin^2 \alpha − 2\sin^2 \beta=0 
$$
Find the values of $\cos 2\alpha$ and $\cos 2\beta$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Questions showing no effort tend to be voted down, and are usually closed.

Comment: If you express the sines in terms of the cosines you get a linear system for $\cos^2\alpha$ and $\cos^2\beta$.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do subtraction on both sides of the equation, then you have

$$
\begin{align*}3\cos^2\alpha-3\sin^2\alpha + 2\cos^2\beta+2\sin^2\beta= 4-0=4\end{align*}
$$

By rearranging, there is $3(\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha)+2(\cos^2\beta+\sin^2\beta) = 4$, then you can find one of the values using trigonometric identities. You can find the other one in a similar fashion.